# Keep nstimer alive when going back to previous viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is a created nstimer object with objective-c. It is working fine while app is background on phone but when i going back to previous viewcontroller, everything is resetting.

Updated:

@property NSTimer *timer;

```
-(void)starter{

if ([_timer isValid]) {
    [_timer invalidate];
    [_startStopBtn setTitle:@"START" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else{

    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                                              target: self
                                            selector:@selector(increaseSecond)
                                            userInfo: nil repeats:YES];

    [_startStopBtn setTitle:@"END WORKOUT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

}

-(void)increaseSecond{

```
[self checkOtherSecond];
```

-(void)checkOtherSecond{

```
    [self increaseMinute];
```

}

this is the code for timer. Its counting seconds and minutes and later hours.

I need create timer object to AppDelegate, but then?

Comment: What do you mean when yo say, "go back to previous viewcontroller"? Back as in a navigation controller or dismissing a view controller?

Comment: If you want to create a timer which should alive for application life cycle, then create that timer code in AppDelegate file. Instead of viewcontroller , write the timer code in AppDelegate

Comment: @LucasDerraugh actually like that: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; Wolverine I'm gonna try that, thank you!

Comment: Ya, you don't want to lose a reference to the timer, so @Wolverine suggestion is a good idea.

Comment: and thats bring another question. I'm using it like that: -(void)starter{ if ([_timer isValid]) {[_timer invalidate]; [_startStopBtn setTitle:@"START" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; } else{ _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target: self selector:@selector(increaseSecond) userInfo: nil repeats:YES];[_startStopBtn setTitle:@"END WORKOUT" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; } } . should i create buttons and selector on appdelegate too?

Comment: No, You need to write the timer logic in AppDelegate. Create you START and END button in ViewController. And on click, call the methods of timer which you have created in AppDelegate. You can access AppDelegate in your app very easily.

Comment: @Wolverine, I tried but dont fit on my mind. Can you give me example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

Add property of `NSTimer` and `declare methods` in AppDelegate.h It will look like following

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
- (void) startTimer;
- (void) stopTimer;

@end
```

In **AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void) startTimer {
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                                              target: self
                                            selector:@selector(increaseSecond)
                                            userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) stopTimer {
    if ([_timer isValid]) {
        [_timer invalidate];
    }
}

- (void)increaseSecond {
    [self checkOtherSecond];
}

-(void)checkOtherSecond {
    NSLog(@"Method Called on each second.");
}
```

Now In your view controller where your START and STOP button method will be there. Modify them like below.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)btnStartClick:(id)sender {

    AppDelegate *objDelegate =  (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [objDelegate startTimer];

}

- (IBAction)btnStopClick:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *objDelegate =  (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [objDelegate stopTimer];
}
```

When you complete this process, and Bind method to respective buttons in ViewController, you can see that constant logs will be displayed which we put in `"AppDelegate.m"` method.

Comment: Thank you for everything. I just did everything you said but its not starting counting. I think there is something else about it.

Comment: https://github.com/krupanshu/NSTimerSample Download and run this. Here is above code. Thanks for marking it as answer.

Comment: I marked it because i create a new project and it worked. Again, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to create a singleton timer:

```
@interface singletonTimers : NSObject

+(instancetype)shareSingletonTimers;

-(void)setTimes:(int)times;

-(void)startTimer;

-(void)stopTimer;

@end


@implementation singletonTimers

static singletonTimers *_instance;

+ (id)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _instance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
    });

    return _instance;
}

+ (instancetype) shareSingletonTimers
{
    if (_instance == nil) {
        _instance = [[singletonTimers alloc] init];
    }

    return _instance;
}

-(void)setTimes:(int)times{

}

-(void)startTimer{
}

-(void)stopTimer{
}

@end
```

If you create a singleton timer,it will alive for application life cycle.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I dont know how to use singleton :( i'm searching but cant find anything useful

Comment: like this:@property singletonTimers *timer;   _timer = [singletonTimers shareSingletonTimers]; [_timer setTimes:]